# Can I add audio recorder to the sound menu?

Tags: sound

I want to add my audio-recorder to Ubuntu's sound menu.

Sound menu seems to use MPRIS commands over DBus to control the media players. So I could implement a minimal MPRIS for audio-recorder as well. Can I also change the icons that is shown on the sound menu? I mean, can I add my own buttons under the media-player? Audio-recorder needs to display three icons/buttons for START, PAUSE and STOP recording.

References:

- [Sound menu.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu)
- [MPRIS spec.](http://www.mpris.org/2.1/spec/)
- [Audio recorder.](https://launchpad.net/audio-recorder)
- [Annoucement on Ubuntuforums.org.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11287136)

Comment: I would suggest you report a bug or something because this is off-topic (now that I fully understand your intentions). It's better brought up in the appropriate bug tracker or so.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own plugin for the [sound indicator](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sound). Development will probably include going through some of the existing examples for Banshee, Rhythmbox and Exaile.

Your biggest problem is going to be the record button. You can't add new buttons via the plugin. Instead you will have to add that to the sound indicator itself and push the change upstream.